# How to make gravity in Java GUI?

Tags: java

I want to make a program that shows a ball jump when the space bar is pressed, yet I'm not sure how to pull the ball back down (gravity).
Could anyone give me a suggestion?

Comment: It might be easier to Google for *gravity*.

Comment: Well how do you plan to make the ball jump? Having it fall back down is jumping in reverse (for a start).

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile
for an example.
You need to code these equations against time, and then compute the x.y co-ordinates of the ball in your reference frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you should proper trajectory equations with x and y. But there could be another simple way.

You could write increment an integer by x while pressing space.

```
x = x + 5 // if space is clicked
x = x - 1 // per second, pseudo "gravity" - using a thread
// x equals the current height of the ball
// maybe you need a check, that he cant press space, if he is on the ground, 
// because double jumps are not that typical with gravity
```

I know this is not correct way to equate the gravity, but its a simple way for beginners to do (in my opinion)